# Gmail APIを使った署名の取得

Tags: gmail

2015/4/20に廃止されたEmail Settings APIのマイグレーション先のGmail APIで署名(Signature)の取得のエンドポイントが見つからないのですが、
現在API経由でGmailの署名を取得する方法はないのでしょうか